# How to send Read By Group Type request from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wireshark, raspberry-pi4

I'm using Raspberry Pi to connect with Minew S1 Temperature and Humidity Sensor, in order to connect with my sensor I need to send some data to connect with sensor, so at first I tried connect with BeaconSet+ app with sensor, and I captured all those packets and tried to decode those using wireshark, so the first data sent from mobile to sensor is "Read By Group Type Request", what does it mean and how can I mirror it in Raspberry Pi using gatttool or bluetoothctl.
[this link has packet screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VONzz.png)

```
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                              #37 [hci0] 23.110065
      LE Set Scan Enable (0x08|0x000c) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) plen 25                                                                #38 [hci0] 23.110095
        Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
        Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
        Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                #39 [hci0] 23.110613
      LE Create Connection (0x08|0x000d) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                                                                #40 [hci0] 23.210757
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Connection interval: 48.75 msec (0x0027)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 37                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 23.210785
        LE Address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 24
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Unknown (0xffe1)
        Service Data (UUID 0xffe1): a101641cfd48e6d87bab3f23ac
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                         #41 [hci0] 23.210905
        Handle: 64
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                #42 [hci0] 23.211771
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 14                                                                             #43 [hci0] 23.211775
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                    ..........      
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                #44 [hci0] 23.337233
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Features: 0x21 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #45 [hci0] 23.337677
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                               #46 [hci0] 23.532018
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 23
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #47 [hci0] 23.532452
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0003
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                   #48 [hci0] 23.580957
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 10                                                                              #49 [hci0] 23.629552
      ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 5
        Value: 6e52463578
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #50 [hci0] 23.629713
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0005
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                               #51 [hci0] 23.727010
      ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 2
        Value: 0000
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                               #52 [hci0] 23.727179
      ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2
        Handle: 0x0027
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                   #53 [hci0] 23.775948
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64
        Count: 2


> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                           #54 [hci0] 32.502249
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 32.502320
        LE Address: AC:23:3F:AB:7B:D8 (Shenzhen Minew Technologies Co., Ltd.)
        Reason: Connection terminated by remote host (0x03)
```

Thank you.

Comment: When you attempt to connect with `bluetoothctl` to the sensor, have you captured the log on the RPi with `sudo btmon` and taken that into wireshark?

Comment: yeah @ukBaz I checked it in wireshark, but it does not contain "Read By Group Type Request" packet

Comment: Are you still having the issue where it connects and disconnects with `bluetoothctl`? What is the log reporting as the issue for that?

Comment: yeah @ukBaz still I'm facing issue on that, not only with bluetoothctl when I use nrf connect app to connect, the connection automatically disconnects, I added log in post.